# Importing Scalding-produced CSV into MySQL

Tags: mysql, csv, cascading, scalding

I produced a CSV file using Scalding's default `Csv` writer (specifying on the `p` parameter for the path to write to, and not any of the other parameters for *how* to write the CSV data) that I am looking to import into MySql. I am running into a problem on the import.

Example queries to load the data:

```
CREATE TABLE `example_table` (
 `a` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `b` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `c` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '~/example.csv'
 INTO TABLE example_table
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
   OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(a,b,c)
```

Example data (i.e. `~/examples.csv`):

```
row1,this is neither quoted nor enclosed,"This is quoted, and contains a comma"
row2,"this is enclosed","This is quoted, and contains a comma"
row3,""this"" is quoted at the start,"This is quoted, and contains a comma"
row4,"""this"" is quoted at the start and enclosed","This is quoted, and contains a comma"
```

When I run the queries with the data file, the resulting table is (excuse the formatting, I can't figure out how to make a table nicely here):

```
row1|this is neither quoted nor enclosed|This is quoted, and contains a comma
row2|this is enclosed|This is quoted, and contains a comma
row3|"this" is quoted at the start,"This is quoted, and contains a comma|NULL
row4|"this" is quoted at the start and enclosed|This is quoted, and contains a comma
```

Row 3 is malformed, and is how Scalding outputs CSV if that field equals `"this" is quoted at the start` (i.e. it has quotes at the beginning of the string, and doesn't contain the field delimiter, in which case it would look like row 4).

Is there a way screwing with the `FIELDS TERMINATED BY`, `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY`, etc options in MySql to get it to import the fields correctly?